# Creating a Pdf with a cartesian grid using itext?

Tags: java, itext

Could anyone please provide me a sample program to create a pdf which can dynamically create a grid or even dots starting at (0,0) at bottom left corner on the Pdf of PageSize.Letter either using itext or any other framework
max X= 8.5 Inches
Max Y =11 Inches

Comment: You're not even trying, you're just asking for it.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [Grid](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/Grid) example (you can download the full code [here](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/Grid)). In this example, I define the `pagesize` variable like this:

```
Rectangle pagesize = PageSize.LETTER;
```

I use this variable to create the `Document` instance, and I also use it in the loops that draw the grid:

```
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
for (float x = 0; x < pagesize.getWidth(); ) {
    for (float y = 0; y < pagesize.getHeight(); ) {
        canvas.circle(x, y, 1f);
        y += 72f;
    }
    x += 72f;
}
canvas.fill();
```

In this case, I increment `x` and `y` with 72 user units. This means that the distance between the dots will be 1 inch.